# Разбор регулярки в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобрать регулярку

```
(/^['"\s\-.*0-9\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+$/.test(name)
```

не понятно с \-.* и дальше

и вторая проблема. Почему не работает отрицание?

```
var name="s34535fs+ddfgdfg35345dfgf";
name=name.replace(/^([a-zа-яё])+/g, "");
console.log(name);
```

как заставить работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Это указывается диапазон юникодных символов. Если гуглить их, то можно подробнее узнать.
2. Отрицание должно быть внутри квадратных скобок сразу после `[`.

Символ `^` в начале регулярки указывает, что совпадение должно быть уже с начала строки.

Символ `$` в конце строки указывает, что совпадение будет до конца строки